# как в объект Q передать значение переменной

Tags: django, python-3.x, queryset

Есть задача в объект Q передать переменную.

Запрос к БД:

```
 data = Module.objects.filter(Q(plug_module='1') | Q(plug_module='2'))
```

рассматриваю 2 варианта 
1) передать переменную `select = "plug_module='1'"` Эта переменная может меняться.
2) передать полностью готовый запрос типа `Q(plug_module='1') | Q(plug_module='2')` в `Module.objects.filter()`

```
per = "Q(plug_module='1') | Q(plug_module='2')"
data = Module.objects.filter(per)
```

Возможно ли так сделать или нет?
Смысл генерировать автоматически QuerySet запросы в зависимости от данных пришедших с web.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, чего вы хотите добиться. Вам динамически нужно создавать набор Q объектов? Или фильтровать какое-либо поле по нескольким вариантам значений?

Comment: Мне надо динамически создавать Q объекты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хотите получить выборку содержащую все указанные значения какого-либо поля, возможно, вам поможет [field lookup in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
Module.objects.filter(plug_module__in=['1', '2'])
```

Если нужны сложные генерируемые фильтры с Q:

```
from operator import __or__ as OR
from django.db.models import Q

query_filters = [
    Q(plug_module='1'),
    Q(plug_module='2')
]
Module.objects.filter(reduce(OR, query_filters))
```

Пример только для наглядности, по сути он бессмысленный, можно упростить до первого варианта.

UPD

```
lookup = {'plug_module': ['1', '2']}
filter_kwargs = {'%s__in' % field: value for field, value in lookup.items()}
Module.objects.filter(**filter_kwargs)
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет по field lookup in. Вопрос был о том как подсунуть в 'Module.objects.filter(plug_module__in=['1', '2'])' вместо 'plug_module__in=['1', '2']' поставить переменную в которой постоянно будет меняться plug_module

Comment: Парамтеры передаются в фильтр как именнованные аргументы, можно их передавать как словарь. Пример в UPD.

Comment: Огромное спасибо тебе, очень сильно помог. Я новичок в этом деле :). только в коде UPD есть ошибка с - `value in lookup.iteritems()` не заработало, поменял на - `value in lookup.items()` и все заработало. еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Моя ошибка, да. Это код для Python 2. Сейчас вижу, что в тегах вопроса у вас Python 3.